# VS code issues with recognising tags as headers

Tags: visual-studio-code, tags, markdown

I have been writing markdown documents in VS code and I would like to know the way to add "tag" in a .md file?

I tried to insert tags in my example.md

```
# Title
#tag1 #tag2

document content...
```

The related plugins installed in my VS code are Markdown All in One + Markdown Preview Enhanced

**Issue:** VSCode recognized those tags as headers.

So how to let VS code recognize those as tags?

Thanks in advance for any help or clues!

Comment: What do you mean by "tags"? A HTML tag is the angle-bracket text that delimits an element. FWIW, Markdown uses `#` to denote headers.

Comment: If you mean you want to have a typographical "hashtag" as plaintext in your Markdown document, then you escape it with a backslash, so `\#tag1`.

Comment: Hi @Dai, sorry for not making it clear. Yes, I want to create hashtag for my notes, so that when I click one hashtag of a note, it will link me to somewhere that presents all notes with the same hashtag. I tried `\#tag1` but it didn't give what I expected. Do I need to create something like hashtag directry to achieve that goal? Thanks!

Comment: Markdown doesn't have any concept of a hashtag or taxonomy system at all - implementing a taxonomy system for tagging is far beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks @Dai ! I will see how to do it with other tools